# How do I deploy a site?

Tags: 8, composer

I am following [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies#download-core) link to set-up a Drupal 8 site, I am installing [drupal-composer/drupal-project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) as a template for my composer install for the first time, as I forced myself into drupal 8 for future reasons. I am not a developer myself.

Forth point of the installation says that:

> ...
>
> 4. Modify the composer.json file to configure your preferred installation
>      paths. It is highly recommended to use a sub-directory such as
>      webroot, www, html, web, etc... when scaffolding your Drupal web site.
>
> ...

Why?

Why is it recommended and what would happen if I don't do it.

I am not able to find any decent documentation anywhere mentioning this, and I am pretty sure though that it is not drupal-specific, so please give some light on this.

How do I deploy this site, as on my localhost, I access the site as `my.dev/web` and I want to use `mysite.com` instead of `mysite.com/web` when I put it online. I am avoiding redirecting with .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Drupal project is often/usually more than just the webroot, there are other files/folders that can be part of a project. Two specific examples are the private files folder, and the configuration folder. Storing these out of the webroot acts as a layer of security, as they are not web accessible. The configuration folder is one that is managed with Git, allowing for deployment of a project to different environments.

> on my localhost, I access the site as `my.dev/web` and I want to use `mysite.com` instead of `mysite.com/web` when I put it online.

You do not need to put your site in a sub-directory. Using cpanel as an example, the default webroot is at `/home/example/public_html`. You can create a symlink from `/home/example/web` to `/home/example/public_html` (or the other way around, I get them mixed up). Then you create your project at `/home/example`. The `web` directory then becomes `/home/example/web` - which points at `/home/example/public_html` due to the symlink.

I wrote a blog post that gets into the topic in more depth: https://www.morpht.com/blog/drupal-and-composer-part-2-managing-drupal-8-site-composer

Comment: Will do that, thanks for the answer.

Comment: I wished a simple answer and you provided with an amazing guide, you are the boss man 8)